# writing a closure in coffeescript with using "do"

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, closures

I am trying to set the property of my Backbone view class using a HTML select in Coffeescript and what I've realised is that I need to inject this(@) into the callback/handler via a javascript closure to maintain scope. But I can't seem to figure out how to do this as using "do" just executes the function on page load

```
dropdown = $('<select />') .on 'change', do(myView = @) -> myVieW.prop = @.value
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `do` notation does compile to an IIFE, yous still need the actual handler function:

```
dropdown = $('<select />') .on 'change', do(myView = @) -> (e) -> myVieW.prop = @.value

# or wrap the whole handler assignment:
do(myView = @) ->
  dropdown = $('<select />') .on 'change', (e) -> myVieW.prop = @.value
```

Or you just use lexical `this`:

```
dropdown = $('<select />') .on 'change', (e) => @.prop = e.target.value

dropdown = $('<select />') .on 'change', (e) => @.prop = dropdown.val()
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of doing it in Backbone is the following:

```
class MyView extends Backbone.View
  events:
    'change select': 'onChange'

  onChange: (e) ->
    el = e.currentTarget
    @prop = el.value
```

Having said that, setting some properties on the view is also a smell, and hints on a missing model.

Setting some property outside of the view is a definite smell and invites re-assessment of the architecture.